# “NSAttributedString initWithData: options: documentAttribute: error:” not working when <img src/> tag given in iOS 10

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Before iOS 10 below code gives me proper result but not after iOS 10. No idea how could iOS version cause the problem.

```
NSString *string = @"<img width=\"30%\" src=\"https://private_server.com/sample_endpoint/example.png\" border=\"3\" />";

NSError *error = nil;
[_textView setAttributedText:[[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithData:[string dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options:@{NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType} documentAttributes:nil error:&error]];
```

No error observed when allocating NSAttributedString but in console below warning is printed.

> objc[88018]: Class PLBuildVersion is implemented in both
>   /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssetsLibraryServices.framework/AssetsLibraryServices
>   (0x1111a4998) and
>   /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PhotoLibraryServices.framework/PhotoLibraryServices
>   (0x110639d38). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.

Breaking my head on this for hours. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Have you tried on real device?

Comment: Same problem occurs in device also @Andrea

Comment: may be privacy issue add key  <key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
<string>Photo Library Access Warning</string>

Answer (score 0):

It seems a bug, check bug report at:

http://www.openradar.me/27820992

Problem may be because of `PLBuildVersion` is defined in both `PhotoLibraryServices.framework` and `AssetsLibraryServices.framework`, so which one to use is undefined.

Possible solutions could be:

Setting following keys into your Info.plist file

1. Photo

   Key:  Privacy - Photo Library Usage Description Value:  $(PRODUCT_NAME) photo use
2. Camera

   Key:  Privacy - Camera Usage Description Value:  $(PRODUCT_NAME) camera use

Hope this will help:)

Comment: There is no such file called `PLBuildVersion.m` in my project.